# Json não existe no namespace *using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json*

Tags: c#, json, .net

Ocorreu um erro ao tentar importar *using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json*.
Como resolver?

O código converte Json para Object e vice versa, estou postando apenas uma parte dele.

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
namespace Converte_Object_Json
{
    public class JsonConversao
    {
        public string ConverteObjectParaJSon<T>(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
                string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                ms.Close();
                return jsonString;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Erro:
[image: Erro]

**Informações do aplicativo:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Versão 16.0.4
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.0.4+28803.452
Microsoft .NET Framework
Versão 4.7.03190

Versão Instalada: Community

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.0.12313.64372

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.0.12313.64372

*É incrível como a maioria dos brasileiros são tao podres, não importa o quanto você se dedica a algo vai ter sempre um filho da p*** que vai negativar sua pergunta sem contribuir com merda nenhuma*

Comment: Olhe essa solução https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255640/why-cant-i-reference-system-runtime-serialization-json-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

O mais provável é que você não tenha a referência adicionada.
Pra isso vá nas referências > botão direito > adicionar referência e selecione a dll abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]